# Duplicate rows based on the length of remaining group values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to duplicate rows based on the length of remaining group values, as seen below.

```py
df_inp = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    }
)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "y": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
        "z": [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8]
    }
)
```

How would I do this in a Pythonic way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the logic you're looking to implement here? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (df_inp
 .groupby('x')
 .apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(combinations(g['y'], 2), columns=['y', 'z']))
 .reset_index('x')
)
```

output:

```
   x  y  z
0  a  1  2
1  a  1  3
2  a  1  4
3  a  2  3
4  a  2  4
5  a  3  4
0  b  5  6
1  b  5  7
2  b  5  8
3  b  6  7
4  b  6  8
5  b  7  8
```

Comment: @JunChoi maybe try to explain a bit more the logic in your question for future readers ;)